# Why have I started having problems reading and mounting a disk in Windows 10?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, mount

Windows 10 Pro 21H1, Ryzen 7 5800X, ROG STRIX X570-E GAMING Rev X.0x, 32GB memory

I have two 8TB drives for archiving, one main and the other backup. I was using a USB bay because I wanted to keep them separate from the system. I ended up connecting the main drive to the motherboard, but use diskpart to mount the drive when needed, then unmount. This has been working fine.

Today when I ran the script to mount the drive, diskpart hung. Windows then began hanging on shutdown and startup from not reading the drive info. Placing the drive in the bay and running chkdsk showed no issues. Connecting to the motherboard again, Windows will boot, but diskpart still hangs and I cannot mount the drive. I have no issues with other drives connected to the motherboard.

Why has my motherboard or BIOS begun having problems with this disk? I have not tried connecting the other 8TB disk to the motherboard. The drive is a Seagate BarraCuda 8TB Internal ST8000DM004.

Spin up time always causes a delay in diskpart. I waited a long time. Also the hang in shutdown and restart indicates an issue reading the disk.

SMART info uploaded at  https://dmcdivitt.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/EpqFy7s8Wq5NlMa6IC_kskgBVn0tZjFKiz8D7gpNqwgmDw?e=ISOboe

No login, all have access.

Comment: Show us the disk SMART data. If you don't already have an application for that, you could use [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).

Comment: Edited to include SMART data link.

Comment: If the drive works when connected via USB and fails when connected with a SATA data cable, I would suspect the SATA data cable.

Comment: Please pick a website for the SMART info that doesn't require a login.

Comment: It does not require a login. Did you try it?